# UICollectionView supplementary view in interface builder

Tags: ios, interface-builder, uicollectionview

For UICollectionViewCell, you can drag&drop a cell in interface builder. Then you can call dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier in your datasource and everything works just fine.

But how are you supposed to do this with accessory views? I tried drag&dropping a new UICollectionReusableView from the sidebar and I also tried enabling the footer option of the collection view.

In both cases I get the error "could not dequeue a view of kind". Sure you can register the class, but then you have to add all your subviews programmatically.
Or you can use a separate xib file and register that. However I like to keep everything within the collection view instead of having a separate xib file for every view.

You don't have to register the cells, then why should you have to explicitly register the supplementary cells.

What's the trick to do this in interface builder?

Comment: If I set the flow layout to have header and footer, I am able to set them up in the storyboard and dequeue them OK.  Forgive me asking - are you using the correct reuseID?

Comment: It only works if I first call registerClass(_ cellClass: AnyClass?, forCellWithReuseIdentifier identifier: String). If I edit out this call, it stops working. This indicates that the reuseID is ok.

Comment: That indicates that you are using the same reuseID in your `registerClass` and `cellForItemAtIndexPath` functions, but it doesn't confirm that the reuseID in the storyboard is the same.  Double check in the Attributes Inspector.

Comment: I have checked the storyboard, I have copied/pasted the string, I have deleted and recreated the cell. Doesn't work.

Comment: Please can you post your code?